# TLS 1.2 implementation on my Azure Cloud service

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-devops, tls1.2

Team,

I have an updated version of Azure Cloud service using SDK 2.9. Its a part of  entire .NET MVC solution upgraded to .net framework 4.6.1.

there is a requirement to use TLS 1.2 on the cloud project ...am not sure what it is and how am I supposed to implement it. Can anyone please help me ?

I have read that TLS 1.2 is enabled by default on the application using the latest framework. > 4.0

How to confirm its working ?

Comment: Take a look at this [case](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79952/hardening-ssl-tls-on-azure-cloud-service-for-a-on-qualys-ssl-labs). Maybe it's helpful.

Comment: thanks Charles...how will the client confirm that the site is now using the TSL 1.2?

Comment: Check out this site: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/  It tests your TLS configuration and provides an overall security review for free.